# restore alfresco data using alf_data directory and database

Tags: server, alfresco, restore, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I had a problem with one of my Alfresco servers and could only recover the alf_data directory and the database. How can I restore my server using both backups that I have?

I tried to restore by following the following steps: 1- make a fresh installation of Alfresco on a new server, 2- replace the alf_data directory of the new server with that of the old server, 3- connect the new Alfresco server to the old Alfresco database, 4- start the Alfresco service. Despite all this, it did not work. Can I please have a solution?

After reviewing the logs in '../tomcat/logs', I encountered this error: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03180018 Ensure that the 'dir.root' property '/opt/alfresco-com/alf_data' is pointing to the correct data location.
this is a capture of error

Answer (score 1):

The procedure you describe is more or less the way how o restore Alfresco but The error you describe means the database does not fit to the `data_dir/contentstore`, so you may not have configured or restored the database correctly or you use the wrong database.

Maybe your `alfresco-global.properties` is not catched up and default configuration applies?

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure seems to be good but an important thing to know is that your database has to be OLDER than your contentstore. Please ensure your database is newer because if not, it will not find all the nodes in your old contentstore. This is the purpose of your error message.

So to perform a successful restore, you must have a couple of backups of contentstore and database made at the same time, during a cold backup (better solution), or made during a hot backup, dumping the database BEFORE copying the contentstore.

Good luck to you